# Run a hidden .bat file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, hidden

I have a bat file that starts a program and already put my username and password, and I have to let the cmd open for the program to work. I want to hide the cmd window to prevent me from closing accidentally, here's the code:

```
*prgram.name* -o *server* -u *username* -p *password*
```

I need this hidden from eyes, but appearing in the task manager to close when I want it...
Thanks

Comment: Are you searching for the `start` command to let the cmd exit before the application terminated? In that case you might as well consider to just create a launcher for the application and insert the parameters there. Or are you searching for a way to programatically execute a batch file without a window? That is possible, but please tag your language and add the code you have in that case.

Comment: With a simple Google search you can find many techniques on how to do this. Here is one that exists on [su] http://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I hide ms-dos window when running a .bat file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580474/how-can-i-hide-ms-dos-window-when-running-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 1):

hide.vbs:

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "*prgram.name* -o *server* -u *username* -p *password*", 0 , false
```

this will run the cmd hidden.

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility called `CMDOW` that can launch a cmd window that is hidden, amongst other things.
Some AV tools flag it as a hack tool because of that.