# How to run a command in the background on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, background-process

In linux you can use *command* **&** to run command on the background, the same will continue after the shell is offline. I was wondering is there something like that for windows…

Comment: Good question, but should be asked at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).  As far as I know, there is no such facility.  Windows uses Services for background tasks with no shell, but they have to be specially coded - you can't just run any command as a service.  The closest you'd get would maybe be the `start` command, which starts a new shell.

Comment: @paddy but if I use `start` it will stop running as soon as I get offline right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. processes started with `start` are terminated when you log out. So it's not suitable for long-running remote background jobs.

Comment: [Superuser has the answer](http://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background), @paddy.

Comment: Your question contains an invalid assumption.  Commands started with & will die with the shell.  So in that sense `start /b` in Windows is the same as & in *nix.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want to do is run a command without an interface (possibly automatically?). On windows there are a number of options for what you are looking for:

- Best: write your program as a windows service. These will start when no one logs into the server. They let you select the user account (which can be different than your own) and they will restart if they fail. These run all the time so you can automate tasks at specific times or on a regular schedule from within them. For more information on how to write a windows service you can read a tutorial online such as (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx).
- Better: Start the command and hide the window. Assuming the command is a DOS command you can use a VB or C# script for this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580474/how-can-i-hide-ms-dos-window-when-running-a-bat-file) for more information. An example is:

  ```
  Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  objShell.Run("C:\yourbatch.bat"), 0, True
  ```

  You are still going to have to start the command manually or write a task to start the command. This is one of the biggest down falls of this strategy.
- Worst: Start the command using the startup folder. This runs when a user logs into the computer

Hope that helps some!

Comment: if you only have VS express then this is a way to create a windows service: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106742/Creating-a-simple-Windows-Service

Comment: Save the VB Script with the extension ".vbs"

Comment: What's about Task Scheduler. Can we add a task to the scheduler using console? And or stop/kill when deploying a new version? What's about restarting the app in case of any errors?

Answer (score 74):

I believe the command you are looking for is `start /b *command*`

For unix, `nohup` represents 'no hangup', which is slightly different than a background job (which would be `*command* &`.  I believe that the above command should be similar to a background job for windows.

Comment: question: start /b *command* will stop running as soon i logoff from the server right? and yes, sorry I is `command &` not `nohup`

Comment: See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3382087/1751190  I believe so, but I'm not positive.  I would test it myself, but I'm not near a windows computer right now.

Comment: Just as a confirmation: yes, the command WILL DIE if you log off (if you connected on the windows machine from a telnet to run the command).

Answer (score 13):

Use the `start` command with the `/b` flag to run a command/application without opening a new window. For example, this runs `dotnet run` in the background:

```
start /b dotnet run
```

You can pass parameters to the command/application too. For example, I'm starting 3 instances of this C# project, with parameter values of `x`, `y`, and `z`:

[image]

## To stop the program(s) running in the background: `CTRL + BREAK`

In my experience, this stops all of the background commands/programs you have started in that `cmd` instance.

According to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc770297(v=ws.11)):

> CTRL+C handling is ignored unless the application enables CTRL+C processing. Use CTRL+BREAK to interrupt the application.

Answer (score 5):

You should also take a look at the `at` command in Windows. It will launch a program at a certain time in the background which works in this case.

Another option is to use the `nssm` service manager software. This will wrap whatever command you are running as a windows service.

UPDATE:

`nssm` isn't very good. You should instead look at WinSW project. https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw

Answer (score 5):

If you take 5 minutes to download visual studio and make a Console Application for this, your problem is solved.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace BgRunner
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting: " + String.Join(" ", args));
            String arguments = String.Join(" ", args.Skip(1).ToArray());
            String command = args[0];

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command);
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(command);
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Examples of usage:

```
BgRunner.exe php/php-cgi -b 9999
BgRunner.exe redis/redis-server --port 3000
BgRunner.exe nginx/nginx
```

Comment: Probably not the sort answer the OP was hoping for, but publishing the source code deserves an upvote, so +1.

Comment: well, this doesn't work for calc.exe https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Aqh.png

Comment: also definitely flashes up a cmd prompt for a moment if i do (tested from win7), "start".."run".. `c:\users\user\abc\a.exe c:\users\user\abc\bb.bat`

Comment: Whoever downloads Visual Studio in 5 Minutes has better internet than my university. x)

Answer (score 5):

It's unimaginable that after a decade that Windows still doesn't have a decent way to run commands in background.

`start /B command` is the most given answer, but the command will be closed when the terminal closed.

Now, Windows 10 have a built-in(you have to install it mannually though) ssh server. you can run

```
ssh username@localhost "my_backgroud_command --params"
```

and then CTRL C, close the terminal, the command will continue to run in background.

This is the most decent way I have found so far.
Although not decent enough, because you have to install and configure the ssh server first.

Comment: This is incorrect as far as I can tell. I just tried it on Windows 10 Pro where I ran `start /b notepad` and the Notepad process started, my `cmd` prompt was released and when I exited `cmd`, Notepad was still running.

Comment: We are talking about "running commands in background". Notepad  is a GUI application, I don't think it has anything to do with "running in background".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. To me "background" simply meant "detached", as in "not dependent on the parent process".

Comment: for "detached", skip the `/b` switch, which basically says "don't open a new window, run in this window"

Answer (score 2):

To **run a command in background on windows cmd**
Add prefix "start /B" with it. Below code run cmd1 in background.

start /B cmd1

To **run multiple command parallelly on windows cmd**, we can run using belowe command in cmd.

start /B cmd1 & start /B cmd2

Answer (score 1):

An option I use frequently when I need to run a simple command, or set of commands, in the background and then log off, is to script the command(s) (BAT, CMD, PowerShell, et al. ... all work fine) and then execute the script using Windows native Task Scheduler.  Jobs that are executed from the Task Scheduler do not die when you log off.  Task Scheduler jobs can be configured to run as "hidden" i.e. the command prompt window will not be displayed.  This script + Task Scheduler is a great alternative rather than developing an executable (e.g. yadda.exe) in your favorite development environment (e.g. Visual Studio) when the task at hand is simple and writing a console application to execute a simple command or two would be "overkill" i.e. more work than it's worth.

Just my two cents.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I come with an update in Windows 11's PowerShell.

The command `start /b something.exe` didn't work in PowerShell as it didn't hide the window of output.

Here is what works in PowerShell:

```
start -FilePath something.exe -WindowStyle Hidden
```

You can refer to the full document:

> NAME
> Start-Process
>
> SYNTAX
> Start-Process [-FilePath]  [[-ArgumentList] <string[]>] [-Credential ] [-WorkingDirectory
> ] [-LoadUserProfile] [-NoNewWindow] [-PassThru] [-RedirectStandardError ] [-RedirectStandardInput
> ] [-RedirectStandardOutput ] [-WindowStyle {Normal | Hidden | Minimized | Maximized}] [-Wait]
> [-UseNewEnvironment]  []
>
> ```
> Start-Process [-FilePath] <string> [[-ArgumentList] <string[]>] [-WorkingDirectory <string>] [-PassThru] [-Verb
> <string>] [-WindowStyle {Normal | Hidden | Minimized | Maximized}] [-Wait]  [<CommonParameters>]
> ```
>
> ALIASES
> saps
> start

Comment: Wrong. It's a `cmd` command and (still) runs in the Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe). `Start` in PowerShell (which is obviously is what you use) is not the same `start` command from `cmd.exe`, but an alias for the PowerShell command `Start-Process`, which has a completely different syntax (because it's running in a completely different environment with a completely different language)

Comment: Correct. I edited the answer to highlight that it works on PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

On a windows server here, use a title (in double brackets) , otherwise it will not "release" :

start "" "chrome.exe --parameters" && echo truc