# Batch - start a cmd window with a command, but run in the background

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The title says it all: i want to start a cmd window with a command, but i want the window hidden

```
start cmd.exe /k "my command"
```

This does what I want, but the cmd window remains open, and upon closing i end the command too. I want to run the cmd.exe in the background. Is it possible?

Comment: Using `start /min "" "cmd.exe" "echo I look amazing etc.."` you can start a cmd window minimized, but as for completely hidden @user3558618 has the answer with the `/b` option.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the `/K` option - the background process will never end. I think you want to use `/C` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was answered here: [How to run a command on the background on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031171/how-to-run-a-command-on-the-background-on-windows)

Basically, you just need the /b option from the start command.

If that does not help, go the VB way, creating a .vbs like this:

```
Dim WinScriptHost
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Scheduled Jobs\mybat.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

Comment: Just make sure your background process does not mess with stdin, stderr, or stdout. Or make sure you redirect the standard I/O to/from files. Otherwise things become very confusing when you run in the same window with `/B`.