# How to hide exe from batch file?

Tags: batch-file, exe

I have following code, I want to hide the EXE window when I execute it from the batch file. Is it possible? Please help. (Run exe in background)

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MyService\"
start CliServiceCmd.exe
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"? Do you mean make it hidden on the file system? Or do you mean so that people don't know which exe you are trying to call via the batch file? Not really possible. You could obfuscate it in code (via some form of string concatenation or a system variable), or refer to it via a link, but if someone has access to your batch file's contents, then they can still theoretically reverse engineer the executable used. What's the use case for this requirement? Why do you need to hide the exe?

Comment: What the operating system are you running? My machine runs with win7 and I can start my exe without extension, such as `start ffplay test.avi`. It's fine.

Comment: basically i have service that run in bat file i have add above code in Batch file  and i want to hide run file

Comment: windows 7 i am using

Comment: You can make it as a windows service with different service name from the original file name and call `net start servicename` to start it.

Comment: i have edit my problem

Comment: @AddiKhan Do you mean "I want to run an executable that has a window, but prevent the window from being displayed"? If so, you will need to see if your executable has any specific options to permit this.

Comment: @RB. dear i want run my exe in background.. command window does not show

Comment: @GeminiKeith dear i have simple C# console file that i want run in background  command window does not show

Comment: You could try `start "" "CliServiceCmd.exe"`, with empty "" between `start` and your program.

Comment: If you don't want to spawn a new window, use `start /B`. Alternatively, you can start with the window minimised (`start /MIN`). Or, just don't use start at all!

Comment: @RB. thanks  :) its run that's i want  .. post as answer

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33152424/388389)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a command on the background on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031171/how-to-run-a-command-on-the-background-on-windows)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `START` with different options

**Print help information**

```
START /?
```

**Run without spawning a new window**

```
START /B MyCommand.exe
```

**Run in a minimized window**

```
START /MIN MyCommand.exe
```

Alternativaly, just don't use start - launch your exe directly!

Comment: @AddiKhan One other thing - in English, you wouldn't normally address someone as "Dear" unless you knew them pretty well ;-)

Comment: But no problems :)