# shell_exec blocking the thread not proceeding to next statements in windows

Tags: php, windows, shell, shell-exec

am executing a shell command like below.

```
shell_exec('java -jar sanityTest.jar');
$success = array('status' => "Success",'type' => "execute");
echo json_encode($success);
```

The `shell_exec` command not going to next statement until the execution complete. What I want is to execute it in background, even for Windows.

I tried

```
shell_exec('java -jar sanityTest.jar >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

which is coming to next line but not executing the command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819398/php-exec-command-or-similar-to-not-wait-for-result

Comment: function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}

Answer (score 1):

My solution: use `start /B *my command*`

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
  if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
    pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
  } else { 
    exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &"); 
  } 
}
```

I could have found it by  looking at the right keywords: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21031259/6019417