# Run pre and post commands to npm test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wanted to run pre and post commands while executing npm test.

As a pre command, i wanted to run my .exe which will need for testing and after the testing is completed and i wanted to kill the .exe.

I have add below code in my package.json tried to execute **npm test** command, it is executing batch file and my server.exe is running but my tests are paused.

*Batch file contains the command **start C:\server.exe***

`'test' : 'C:/test.bat && ng test'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a command on the background on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031171/how-to-run-a-command-on-the-background-on-windows).