# Running python script with heroku bash continuously

Tags: python, heroku

I have a script that requires 2 two inputs that are not the same every time. So I have to give the input manually every time I run the script. And I do want to deploy this script to Heroku. But unfortunately, I can't give any kind of input manually in heroku:worker. I can't use any kind of environment variables, arguments because these 2 inputs are not static. So heroku:worker just keeps getting the 'There are no inputs' error.

So I have decided to run the script with the command `heroku run python3 main.py` but no matter what I do I couldn't get out of the terminal without ending the process. I want this script to run continuously even if I get out of the terminal.

So how can I run the python script in Heroku continuously and quit the terminal without breaking the process?

Comment: Sending the input from the terminal is a bad idea as heroku is not designed for that. you should change your scirpt to accept input via http maybe

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander stated Heroku script deploys are not meant to be run frequently like this. It will be worth your time to create a simple Flask server to accept HTTP requests from anywhere (so you can then run your script via `CURL` or Postman). Heroku also has very good tutorials on how to do this if you are unfamiliar.

However if this is a hard requirement that you cannot deploy a simple web server (even though, you really should), let's work around this:

if you are on OSx or any Unix style machine you can background a process with a simple `process script &` i.e., `heroku run my_script.py &`  and to call it to the foreground again, just type `fg`.

I am less familiar with windows but i think you can do `start /b <program>` but in your case you will be better served by the answer provided here [How to run a command in the background on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031171/how-to-run-a-command-in-the-background-on-windows) (if you are running on windows)

Note this is a bad solution and your script will stop running once you close your user session/shut down.

The proper way to be create a web server which takes requests on demand - that way you can pass whatever params you need to whenever you need the script to run.