# Run multiple "npm start" in a single .cmd file

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file, npm, cmd

I'm trying to script everything.
How could I run **multiple instances** of npm start **in one .cmd file** for Windows ?

*Example* : I've got an API which runs with "`npm start`" and a client app which also runs with "`npm start`". I can easily run a single one with :

```
cd D:/my folder/... 
npm start
```

But here, i would like to **open a second command prompt** in order to cd another folder and run another "npm start" with the same .cmd file.

Thank you !

Comment: Can you use `start /b` as discussed here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031171/how-to-run-a-command-in-the-background-on-windows That will run that npm start in the background and you can do other things like launch another one while that runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[npm](/questions/tagged/npm) is really another batch file, so it should be `call`ed. When you `call` a batch file from another, it will return to the caller upon completion:

```sh
@Echo Off
CD /D "D:\Somewhere"
Call "P:\athTo\npm.cmd" start [-- <args>]
CD /D "C:\AnotherPlace"
Call "P:\athTo\npm.cmd" start [-- <args>]
Rem next line if required goes here
```

As your question did not require that both commands needed to be run at the same time, *(or that a second Command Prompt was a necessity)*, the answer above is based upon that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by running multiple .cmd files from the first one, and then exiting it, like this :

```
cd D:/.../folder
start script1.cmd
start script2.cmd
exit
```

This way, you can run as many commands as you want, and even with different titles etc.
Kind of messy, but everyone needs a folder full of .cmd files, right ?

Comment: I cannot agree. I don't need a folder full of cmd files as I know how to code a batch file correct for a task to accomplish with a batch file. The command `exit` at end of a batch file is never necessary and is just counterproductive on running the batch file from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on the batch file. So I would strongly recommend to remove `exit` at end of your batch file.