# PHP: PHP -S in background

Tags: php

is there a way to execute `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` but in background

Something simiar to `-d` in docker.

Thank you

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 11, the point is to introduce more commands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a command in the background on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031171/how-to-run-a-command-in-the-background-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

This would put your process in the background. you can see the background processes by running a `ps` command

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/ > output.log 2>&1 &
```

the logs or output of your process will be available in the file `output.log`.

Comment: The point is to let me introduce more commands but it locks the terminal. https://i.imgur.com/Ta6sFg7.png

Comment: You can check it better on this image https://i.imgur.com/Ppd8qPg.png

Comment: I see. I was thinking you were on linux or windows. maybe you could try it with the windows subsystem for linux. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install